# Best way to Implement Error handling on html onclick event

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs

I have below div & onclick event

```
     <div
        className={classes.couponCodeButton}
        onClick={() => {
          setCodeContainer(!openCodeContainer);
          EventTracking('cart_promo_code_form',!openCodeContainer);
        }}
      >
```

`EventTracking` is my custom added function in this, i am not sure how do i implement error handling in this, since i have added it in html, i am not sure if i can add try catch in html div.

Is their any way i can implement error handling in this ?

Thankyou

Comment: no thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of ways to do this. Simple create a function and catch an error in this function. I created for you a simple example. You can check it out here [error handling example](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-joliot-sy765?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am facing syntax error on this line -   EventTracking('coupon_actions',{session,'Coupon Applied'}); can you please advise how to correct it ?

Comment: can you create a sandbox or snippet code for error?